# EPPlus - ExcelPackage loading multiple sheets from a Stream/FileInfo generates an excel document with no data

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I am trying to convert a byte array (or Stream, or FileInfo) to an Excel file in C#. For this I am using EPPlus which seems a very nice component to deal with Excel files.
I already know that the byte array is a valid Excel file already having at least one worksheet (may have more than one). What I need, is to convert the byte array to a valid Excel file so that I can modify it prior to return it back a byte array.

But the problem that I am having, is that whenever I create the ExcelPackage object and load the excel document (either as MemoryStream or as FileInfo), the Excel document gets the correct worksheet name and even freezes the rows that are already frozen in the original document, but it has not data in it!

Below is a test piece of code of what I was trying to do:

```
    private ExcelPackage ByteArrayToExcelPackage(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        ExcelPackage package;
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // In the following two lines, the Excel file is saved correctly on file system. This means that the byte array is a valid Excel file with data on it
        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, $"tempFiles/{guid}.xlsx");
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, arrBytes);

        // In the following 4 lines, I just try to load now the just saved file. It looks like the file is loaded correctly, but no data are available in the worksheet!!!
        var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        var fileInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var file1 = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, $"tempFiles/{guid}_1.xlsx"));
        package = new ExcelPackage(file);
        package.SaveAs(file1);

        //TODO: In the following piece of code just make the changes needed on Excel document
        foreach (var sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            sheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
            sheet.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;
        }

        return package;
    }
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Tested your code, it works fine. I can open both excel files generated with `File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, arrBytes)` and `package.SaveAs(file1);`.

Comment: In my case, no, it doesn't work. SaveAs method simply saves an Excel file with no data at all. I don't know what I am missing and since for the others seem to work, I don't think it's a bug of the component.I have tried so many other options but all of them produce same result: Empty file!
I have also upgraded EPPlus version (was using 4.1) to 4.5.1 but it has exactly the same behavior.